# Unit testing a class that relies on an EJB and UserTransaction

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, ejb, mockito

How do I write a unit test for a class that takes in an EJBContext object?
i.e.

```
public class MyProcessor {    

public MyProcessor (EJBContext ejbContext, SomePojo somePojo) { }

    ReturnObject saveMethod(InputObject inputObject){
         UserTransaction utx = this.context.getUserTransaction();

          try {
             utx.begin();
             ....
             ....
              }
     return ReturnObject;
    }
}
```

I am using mockito and Junit. I have followed a lot of beginners tutorials and can't find anything solid about the class that I want to test.

So far I got this to pass:

```
@Mock
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyProcessorTest{

@Mock
MyProcessor myProcessor;

    @Test
public void testSaveNewAssignment() {   

    InputObject inputObject= new InputObject();

    ReturnObject returnObject = new ReturnObject();

    when(myProcessor.saveMethod(inputObject)).thenReturn(returnObject);

    ReturnObject actualReturnObject= myProcessor.saveMethod(inputObject);

    assertSame(returnObject, actualReturnObject);

}
```

I'm not sure what this is actually doing, and if this is the correct way to go about it.

Many mockito examples use the "new" keyword to instantiate the class that I'm  testing. But when I call the new keyword on MyProcessor, and I guess  mock out the EJBContext and the SomePojo, but I get a java.lang.NullPointerException
error in the UserTransaction utx when I do that.

UPDATE:
Thanks to the answer by RadekSohlich, I used the InjectMocks annotation and didn't make my processor class a mock which is what I was doing (incorrectly of course).

Another interesting thing that was happening was that I had to mock the UserTransaction, and make use of Mockito's "when" keyword to tell it to use that mock. Otherwise I'd have a nullpointerException.

Here is an example of the solution that worked:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyProcessorTest {

@Mock
private InputObject inputObject

@Mock
private UserTransaction utx;

@Mock
private EJBContext context;

@Mock
private SomePojo somePojo

@InjectMocks    
private MyProcessor myProcessor;

public MyProcessorTest() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

when(context.getUserTransaction()).thenReturn(utx);
}

@Test
public void testSaveNewAssignment_instantiate() {

    ReturnObject response = myProcessor.saveMethod(inputObject);

    // no exception encountered
    assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Testing EJB is not simple. Project [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) can realy helps you. With this you can test beans in application server environment directly. Unfortunately you will have deal with specific feature of chosen server.

Comment: Thanks, under any other circumstance I would use Arquillian, but we were stuck with this particular IDE which was hard to set up Arquillian. If we were to use Eclipse, then that would be a definite yes.

Answer (score 2):

Well the key is to use annotation @Mock for objects/beans for objects that your tested bean depends on. For example, I'm testing class AssignmentRest, that depends on AssignmentRepository,FileRepository,SubmissionHelper and PluginService classes, so you have to mock all beans and use annotation @InjectMocks for bean under test. See example:

```
public class AssignmentRestTest extends GenericTest {

@Mock AssignmentRepository assignmentRepo;
@Mock FileRepository fileRepo;
@Mock SubmissionHelper submissionHelper;
@Mock PluginService pluginHolder;

@InjectMocks AssignmentRest assignRest;

public AssignmentRestTest() throws IOException {
    super();
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(assignRest).build();
    RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc = mockMvc;
    presetBeans();
}

public void presetBeans() {
    //Preset the return values
    Mockito.when(pluginHolder.isSupportedLang(anyString())).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    Mockito.when(assignmentRepo.save(any(Assignment.class))).thenReturn(new Assignment("1234", "rada", "C", "Test", "NEW", new Date()));
}

@Test
public void testCreateAssignment() {
    given().body("{\"owner\":\"rada\",\"name\": \"CHistory\",\"lang\": \"C\",\"assignmentId\": \"0\"}")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .when().
            post("/rest/assignment/create").
            then().
            statusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}


@Test
public void testGetAll(){
given().
            when().
            get("/rest/assignment/all/rada").
            then().
            statusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, this worked really well. The InjectMocks annotation was the key to what I was looking for.

Comment: @ArmandoPerea, if it worked, maybe you can mark this as the answer.